# GPS distance calculation turns out too short

Tags: geometry

I have started hiking a few months ago and got myself a Garmin Garmap 62s a bunch of maps, a notebook, and a compass. Now I know the GPS can calculate the distance between 2 points and display it onscreen, however, a group of kids at a camp I was sleeping over asked me how to calculate the distance between 2 coordinates without using the GPS. I do simple Pythagoras `a² + b² = c²`, but when I double-check my answer via the GPS I am always a few kilometers short. Can you please check if my calculations are right?

Point A lat = `26°12'8.7 S"` Point A lon = `28°15'16.9 E"`

Point B lat = `15°23'36 S"` Point B lon = `28°22'58 E"`

---

Get `lat` distance = `26°12'8.7"` - `15°23'36"` = `10°48'32.7"`

Thus for `lat` -> `1° = 111.044km` which is `10 * 111.044 = 1110.4km`

Thus for `lat` -> `1' = 1.849km` which is `48 * 1.849 = 88.752km`

Thus for `lat` -> `1" = 30.78m` which is `32.7 * 30.78 = 1.006Km`

Therefore the `lat` distance or `side a = 1110.4 + 88.752 + 1.006` which is `1200.158km`

---

Get `lon` distance = `28°22'58"` - `28°15'16.9"` = `0°7'41.1"`

Thus for `lon` -> `1° = 87.843km` which is `0 * 87.843 = 0km`

Thus for `lon` -> `1' = 1.463km` which is `7 * 1.463 = 10.241km`

Thus for `lon` -> `1" = 24.384m` which is `24.384 * 41.1 = 1.002Km`

Therefore the `lon` distance or `side b = 0 + 10.241 + 1.002` which is `11.243km`

---

Thus `1200.158² + 11.243² = 1440505.630`

Therefore `side c is the square root of 1440505.630` which is `1200km`

Now my answer is `1200km` but Google Earth says it is `1197km`

Answer (score 1):

Pythagoras theorem doesn't hold for a sphere. To compute distances on Earth's surface, you can use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). Or to get an even more precise result the [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae).

You get the following results based on those two formulas:

```
Haversine:  1201.99
Vincenty:   1196.82
```

Vincenty's formulae are very close to what Google Earth provides as a distance.

I used following Python code to perform the computations:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

from dms2dec.dms_convert import dms2dec
from vincenty import vincenty


def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    r = 6371  # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r


def main():
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(dms2dec,
                                 ['''28°15'16.9"E''',
                                  '''26°12'8.7"S''',
                                  '''28°22'58"E''',
                                  '''15°23'36"S'''])
    print(f"Haversine: {haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2): .02f}")
    print(f"Vincenty:  {vincenty((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)): .02f}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think the issue is not the Pythagorean theorem, but  rather the fact that 1 degree longitude is not always the same distance, it depends on the latitude (eg, at the poles 1 degree of longitude is zero).

Comment: @user619894 You're absolutely right. I have to admit that I read your question too fast. Indeed the distance for one degree of longitude depends on the latitude where it is measured. I'll update my answer. You should use the Haversine formula or even better the Vincenty's formulae.